# jQuery: using $.getJSON to get localization from aprs.fi

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, localization, getjson

I want to use JSON to get localization coordinates from http://aprs.fi/page/api. I found example at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON :

```
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "cat",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

When $.getJSON succed, it runs function(data), it puts 4 images on website. I paste this code in my html file and it works, so I changed it to get JSON data from aprs.fi:

```
<script>    
$.getJSON("http://api.aprs.fi/api/get?name=OH7RDA&what=loc&apikey=_key_&format=json",   
    function(data) 
    {
        alert("Anything");
    });
};
</script>
```

Maybe my query is wrong, but even "Anything" doesn't print on my screen. I have no idea how to change it to make it works.

Comment: Shouldn't it also be a jsonp call as it is cross domain. add jsoncallback=? to the url e.g. http://api.aprs.fi/api/get?name=OH7RDA&what=loc&apikey=_key_&format=json&jsoncallback=?

Comment: The site you're trying to access must understand how to respond to a JSONP request.  I don't see any indication that that site does so.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a service can return JSON-formatted results does not mean that you can access it via JSONP.  The site has to explicitly recognize such a request so that the response works as a JSONP response. (That is, the response must take the form of a function call, with the JSON return data passed as the argument to the function.)

Comment: I have changed ma url to <http://api.aprs.fi/api/get?name=OH7RDA&what=loc&apikey=_key_&format=json&jsoncallback=> but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The XHRs that getJSON is using are subject to same-origin-policy in web browsers; you can point XHR only to from only the exactly same server, port, protocol combination as the web page they are used in. If your web page runs on http://example.org:5625 it can only point XHR requests to http://example.org:5625/some-path-here.

The workaround is called JSONP where the resource is loaded as a  tag. However, the service in question needs to be aware of it. You can tell if it is because after appending the callback parameter it should show something like

```
callbackname({"the": "respose", "goes": "here"});
```

that is, a function call to the named callback. However, if I understood correctly, the service you are using does not support JSONP. Then your only option is to make a serverside script that works as a proxy.